# Avoid setInterval from being Cleared

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, frontend

I have a simple Clock component on my Website, code is given below :

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const Clock = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    setInterval(() => {
      const dateObject = new Date() //` Date Object
      var currentTime = dateObject.getHours() + ' : ' + dateObject.getMinutes()

      setTime(currentTime)

    }, 1000)

  }, [])

  return <div>{time}</div>
}

export default Clock
```

But on some other page I have am running a loop to clear timeouts on that specific page, But what end up happening is my clock interval also get cleared.
*(It is very important to clear timeouts on that page for my desired functionality, this clears out any timeouts currently running.)*
Code for which is :

```js
const highestId = window.setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = highestId; i >= 0; i--) {
    window.clearTimeout(i)
  }
}, 0)
```

I want to keep clock interval running but also cancel all other ones.

Comment: Keep an array of the setTimeout ids and loop through that array to clear them instead of going from 0

Comment: How Can I Store the IDs ,any references on that? Im running timeouts like this
setTimeout(()=>{ Some Code},500)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a track of either `setTimeout` IDs or `setInterval` IDs and then clear just the timeout IDs.

```
/* Make sure the timeoutIDs doesn't get reinitialised everytime you run this code, 
probably store it some central service that remains in memory, or declare it globally
*/
const timeoutIDs = [];
const id = window.setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < timeoutIDs.length; i++) {
    window.clearTimeout(timeoutIDs[i])
  }
}, 0);
timeoutIDs.push(id)
```

OR :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const IntervalSet = new Set();

const Clock = () => {
  const [time, setTime] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {

    const id = setInterval(() => {
      const dateObject = new Date() //` Date Object
      var currentTime = dateObject.getHours() + ' : ' + dateObject.getMinutes()

      setTime(currentTime)

    }, 1000)
    
    set.add(id);

  }, [])

  return <div>{time}</div>
}

export default Clock;
```

```
import { IntervalSet } from 'somePath'; 

const highestId = window.setTimeout(() => {
  for (let i = highestId; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(IntervalSet.has(i)) {
      continue;
    }
    window.clearTimeout(i)
  }
}, 0)
```

Comment: Love You Bro, This Absolutely Worked Flawlessly